# f is an open map iff f is a closed map.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Let X and Y be metric spaces and suppose that f:X --> Y is one one and onto. Show that f is an open map iff it is a closed map.
CLOSED MAP-a function which takes closed sets onto closed sets.
This problem is from functions of one complex variable by John B Conway.

Comment: If you function is one-to-one and onto, then $f(A^{c}) = f(A)^{c}$ for all subsets $A \subseteq X$, where $A^{c}$ is the complement of $A$.

Comment: Your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Do you mean $f : X \dashrightarrow Y$ or $f  : X \rightarrow Y$?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f$ be given to be an  open map .

*To show that $f$ is closed*.

Let $V$ be closed in $X\implies V^c\text{ is open in X}\implies f(V^c)\text{is open in Y}$

Since $f$ is bijective $f(X\setminus V)=Y\setminus f(V)$

So $f(V^c)\text{is open in Y}\implies Y\setminus f(V)$ is open in $Y\implies f(V)$ is closed in $Y$.

Apply the same logic to show that $f$ is open map  given $f$ to be a closed map.